# Radio Buttons to PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, html, button

How can I get the value of a radio button like a "Gender Selector" (Male/Female) to PHP? I really need it for my register.php form. I tried googling it but they didnt provide how to get the value of it just how to generate it.

## Code

```
<form action = "register.php" method = "post">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$sex = $_POST['radiobutton=sex'];
```

Comment: Put radio buttons inside a form. Place Submit button to form.assign values to radio buttons. Place action and method to form. To proccess form using php use variables like $_GET or $_POST

Comment: `$sex = $_POST['sex'];`

Comment: `$_POST['radiobutton=sex']` – that’s total nonsense. Please go read up on the absolute _bascis_ of handling form values in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page with form:

```
<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male'/>Male
    <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female'/>Female
    <input type='submit' name='submit_sex' />
</form>
```

On register.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit_sex']))
    echo 'Gender is ' . $_POST['sex'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs a submit button. When you hit submit, on your `register.php`, you can do

```
$sex = $_POST['sex']
```

What you put in the brackets is what you specify in the `name` attribute for your radio buttons.

Seriously though... you should try to understand the basics of forms in general. Here's a decent [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)